# How cache text in easeljs?

Tags: caching, easeljs

How can i make the cache function work?, the letters disappear!

```
function Tile(obj, stage, tipo) {
  this.color = '#4c3030';
  this.types();

  var text = new createjs.Text(String.fromCharCode(this.obj[tipo].code), this.obj[tipo].size + "px Arial", this.obj[tipo].color);
  text.x = (13 * obj.x) + 150;
  text.y = (13 * obj.y) + 44;
  text.textBaseline = "alphabetic";
  text.cache((13 * obj.x) + 150, (13 * obj.y) + 44, 13, 13);
  stage.addChild(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely because you are caching the wrong coordinates. Caches work *relative* to your object, so if you are top-left-aligned (the default), then you could use [x=0,y=0]. It looks like you are instead using the x/y coordinates where you are positioning your text in its parent.

```
text.cache(0, 0, 13, 13);
```

Note that 13x13 size is quite tiny, and might need to be sized up.

An easy way is to just use the text's bounds. This is relatively accurate, though some font/browser combinations are not perfect:

```
var bounds = text.getBounds();
text.cache(bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);
```

Test it out, and output the bounds to the console and you should be able to get a better idea of how caching works.

Cheers!

Comment: thanks i solve this adding all the shapes in a container, now work correctly.

Comment: Yes, because that is the parent's container, and you were using the text's coordinates in its parent. Makes sense.